# Unique enties of a specific partial column of csv file

Tags: shell, csv, awk, scripting

In a comma separated csv file,2nd column is 10 digit number(eg.7737480463).
I am able to find out total number of unique entries for 2nd column by following command

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' abc.csv|sort|uniq|wc -l
```

But i want to find out total number of unique entries for 2nd column on the basis of first 5 digit(eg.77374).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the substr() function of awk?

```
awk -F, '{ print substr($2,1,5) }' abc.csv | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Or you could do this:

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' abc.csv | cut -c 1-5 | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

But i think you could so it all in one swoop using awk:

```
awk -F, '{ count[substr($2,0,5)] = 1; } END { for(i in count) x++; print x; }' abc.csv
```

Awk has arrays that can have strings as keys (associative array). I use the first five chars of the second column (substr($2,0,5)) as key and write some value (in this case 1) into the array. If the key is repeated the value is simply replaced. In the end i have an array element for each unique key, so i can simply count the number of elements in the array to get the number of unique keys.

Comment: Last example wont work as you are using i in count then manually increasing i. Try doing something like `{ for(i in count) x++; print x;`

Comment: @Mithrandir Kindly explain 3rd method(all in one swoop using awk)

Comment: @user752590 : added some hopefully explaining text

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it in awk

```
awk -F, '!x[substr($2,0,5)]++{i++}END{print i}' abc.csv
```